# ExtJS/Touch - data from models association presented in list

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-touch

I'd like to present some data pulled from php script on list in sencha touch MVC application. I have clients model, and bookings model. The association are simple: clients can have many bookings, booking belong to client.
I created some models

```
App.models.ClientModel = Ext.regModel('ClientModel', {
idProperty: 'clientID',
fields: [
    'clientID',
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'email',
    'phone1',
    'extension1',
    'phone2',
    'extension2',
    'workPh',
    'workExt',
    'address1',
    'address2',
    'city',
    'province',
    'country',
    'reminderType',
    'postal',
    'noteID',
    'referredBy',
    'quickLogin',
    'creationDate',
    'modifiedDate',
    'birthDate'
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url : 'includes/data_api',
    appendId: true,
    extraParams: {
        model: 'Client'
    },
    format: 'php',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    }
},
associations: [
    {type: 'hasMany', model: 'BookingModel', primaryKey: 'bookingId', foreignKey: 'clientID', name: 'bookings'}
]});  

App.models.BookingModel = Ext.regModel('BookingModel', {
idProperty: 'bookingID',
fields: [
    'bookingID', 
    'clientID', 
    'stylistID', 
    'salonID',
    'serviceID', 
    'startDate',
    'splitStartDate',
    'splitEndDate',
    'endDate',
    'status',
    'clientNotes',
    'stylistNotes',
    'reminderSent',
    'charge',
    'offset'
],
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url : 'includes/data_api',
    format: 'php',
    appendId: true,
    extraParams: {
        model: 'Booking'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'items'
    }
},
associations: [
    {type: 'belongsTo', model: 'ClientModel', primaryKey: 'clientID', foreignKey: 'clientID', getterName: 'getClient', name: 'client'}
]});
```

After some fights, I get the hasMany association working with code sampe put in controller:

```
var client = App.stores.ClientStore.getAt(1);
    var bookings = client.bookings();
    bookings.clearFilter();
    bookings.filter('clientID', client.get('clientID'));
    bookings.load();
```

I can't get the belongsTo association working. If I try the code below, I see the request made to php script, but without any additional parameters, so it returns full list of clients, and console.log returns always the first one

```
booking.getClient({
        success: function(client, operation) {
            console.log(client);
        }
    });
```

So, the first question is: how can I get this to work? 
And second question:
How can I get this to work on lists? From what I know I passed only the Store in the configuration object of list. So if I have to made some additional requests just to get the associated data, how can I do this on lists? And how can I refer to associated data in xtemplate for each list item?